# How to extracted fields values from React-jsonSchema

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2016, react-jsonschema-forms

I am trying to use `React-JSONSchema` in application but in meantime when I try to extract values from fields ( which user entered ) I am failed . I really tried but did not find any proper solution to extract my values . could someone please help me how to extract value from fields and update my state . It will be appreciated if someone give it try with example .

Library Link : https://react-jsonschema-form.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 0):

The concept of JSON Schema Form is to provide data as FormData, could you try the `onChange`/`onSubmit` callbacks like demonstrated here: https://react-jsonschema-form.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#usage

here is an example https://codesandbox.io/s/demo-react-json-schema-form-mh9mz (see the file `src/components/player` and the DevTools console)